# How to implement "Update" SpringMVC, Thymeleaf and RestTemplate?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf, resttemplate

I built 2 Spring Boot apps: one a REST API, the other the REST client consuming the API through Rest Template and Thymeleaf. The client basically implements basic CRUD functionalities and consumes the API, and so far I could ONLY have CREATE, READ and DELETE working client side. 
*I am having trouble with the **UPDATE** functionality:
I already have the update() method on the controller but don't know how to connect it to the view template, so that for example if I add an Edit button to each "User" object on the list, clicking on it it should take me to a pre-populated form with the "User" name (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTSZY.png)).

here is my controller code for update():

```
@PutMapping("update")
public String update(@RequestParam Long id, User user ) {
    restClient.update(id, user);
    System.out.println("updated");
    return "redirect:/users";
}
```

I created the RestClient class to perform the CRUD operation using Rest Template:

```
public class RestClient {

    public final String GET_ALL_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/all";
    public final String POST_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/user";
    private static final String DEL_N_PUT_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/";

    private static RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    //get all users
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return Arrays.stream(restTemplate.getForObject(GET_ALL_URL, User[].class))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    //create user
    public User postUser(User user) {
        return restTemplate.postForObject(POST_URL, user, User.class);
    }

    //delete user
    public void delete(Long id){
        restTemplate.delete(DEL_N_PUT_URL+id);
    }

    //update user
    public User update(Long id, User user){
        return restTemplate.exchange(DEL_N_PUT_URL+id, HttpMethod.PUT,
                new HttpEntity<>(user), User.class, id).getBody();
    }
}
```

snippet of view template:
(I already have a "newuser" form working fine)

```
<table class="u-full-width">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="user : ${users}">
        <td th:text="${user.id}"></td>
        <td th:text="${user.name}"></td>
        <td>
            <form th:method="delete" th:action="@{/}">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="${user.id}"/>
                <button type="submit">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[client project GITHUB](https://github.com/desiby/spring-restclient-demo)

Comment: how have you managed your security in your thymeleaf project and rest api project?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call PUT method of RestTemplate like..

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url)
    // Add query parameter
    .queryParam("id",id);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.put(builder.toUriString(), user);
```